# Saxon xslt transform to PDF slow on server but fast on local

Tags: linux, tomcat, saxon, apache-fop

I am facing an performance issue using saxon and apache fo to transform xml to PDF. the pdf we use to test has 85 pages and is around 320k. it spends almost 2 mins on  **transform** method call and in local it only takes less than 5 seconds.
we monitor cpu usage and GC during that method call and found that on server, cpu usage stays steady at 5% and we did not have any limitation on cpu from server side. GC happens every 1 to 2 seconds but they are all minor GC and each one takes only 10 to 50ms.  we also monitor io wait during test and it stayed very low.
libs we are using are：　saxon 9.1 and apache fop 2.1 (we tested with different saxon and apache versions but issue remains)
xml and xsl files are too large so i am not able to post them. below is the sample code from transformation:

```
 public static TransformerFactory transformerFactory;
 public static Transformer xlsProcessor;

 public static byte[] generatePDF(InputStream xmlData, String xslFile)
        throws TransformerException, IOException {


    byte[] fileArray = null;
    InputStream xsltfile = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        xsltfile =
            XmlToPdfGenerator.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(xslFile);

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(xmlData);

        StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(xsltfile);
        if (null== fopFactory){
            File xconf= new File(XmlToPdfGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResource("a xconf file").getFile());
            fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(xconf);
        }
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Transformer xslfoTransformer =
            getTransformer(transformSource);
        if (xslfoTransformer != null) {
        Fop fop;
        try {
            fop =
                fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,
                        foUserAgent, outStream);
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            try {

            xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res);

            fileArray = outStream.toByteArray();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                // some error handling logic omitted
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // some error handling logic omitted
            }
        } catch (FOPException e) {
                // some error handling logic omitted
        }
        }
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
                // some error handling logic omitted
    } catch (Exception e) {
                // some error handling logic omitted
    } finally {
        if (null != xsltfile) {
        xsltfile.close();
        }
        if (null != outStream) {
        outStream.close();
        }
    }
    return fileArray;
    }

 private static Transformer getTransformer(StreamSource streamSource) {
   if (null==transformerFactory){
    transformerFactory =
            new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
    }
    try {
        if (xlsProcessor == null) {
            xlsProcessor  =
                transformerFactory.newTransformer(streamSource);
        }
        return xlsProcessor  ;
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // some error handling logic 
    }
    return null;

    }
```

I doubt there is any code issue caused this as it works normal on local.
greatly appreciated if any thoughts on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you haven't provided enough information to diagnose the problem, so all we can do is to offer advice on how to drill down further to get some diagnostic data. It's going to be a lot easier to help if you move to the current version (9.7), and it might even solve the problem.

Check whether the transformation is making any HTTP requests to the W3C server (or elsewhere). For example, to fetch common DTDs. W3C deliberately throttle these requests. Recent releases of Saxon intercept these requests and use a local copy of the file within the Saxon software, but you are using a very old version. There are various tools you can use to monitor HTTP traffic.

Run the transformation on its own without any Apache FOP processing to see how the figures compare. You need to determine whether the problem is during XSLT processing or XSL-FO processing, and the best way to do that is to run one without the other.

Check whether you get the same performance issues when you run the transformation on its own from the command line.

Check the Saxon execution profile obtained using -TP:profile.html, and see how the results compare on the two machines.

Check the Java profile data, e.g. using run=hprof, and see how it compares on the two machines. Any major differences provide a clue for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried version 9.7 and 9.6, issue is still the same. tried only generate fo file and not use apache fo completely and this step only takes like 1 sec.  does this mean the slowness was caused by apache fo side? because I am not sure if Saxon job is done when fo is generated or it also get involved in FO to PDF processing. Also does Saxon has function that generates pdf from FO? Thanks

Comment: If those measurements are correct then your problems are in Apache FOP rather than in Saxon (which means, sorry, I can't help you any further). Saxon isn't involved in the XSL-FO to PDF conversion.

Comment: Thanks, we measured time spent on each different step and it was the XSL-fo to PDF processing took the most of time, so it appears this issue happens on apache fop side.